# Reoder featured articles after migration to joomla 4

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4, featured-articles

I have upgrade my site from Joomla 3.10.x to Joomla 4.3.2.

My homepage shows a list of featured articles. I have create new featured articles and if i change the order in the backend with drag & drop, after refresh the order of the list remain the same, both in backend and frontend.

I have check the tables `_content` and `_content_frontpage` in the db and i cant find the new article ids in the column `content_id`.
If i change with drag & drop the order of an article with an id that exist in the `content_id` column, then the order is changing successfully.

Any ideas on why the new articles dont exist in the `_content_frontpage` table so i can change the order of the featured articles?

Comment: Do they show up ok in the list of Articles? Ie, with a yellow star in the Featured column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news!

I solve the order problem by deleting in table `_content_frontpage` all the rows with the article ids that dont exist in the `_content` table.